# Why doesn't USB 2 speed ever hit the maximum 48MBps?

Tags: usb

What is the limiting factor in USB 2 connections?  The interface is 480Mbps, which equates to 48MB/s after 8b/10b encoding.  I have all sorts of disks and memory cards which can do well over 100MB/s, and they never reach higher than about 34MB/s on USB 2.  I've known about this limitation for years, but I don't know exactly why it isn't closer to 48MB/s.

Comment: One those speeds are theoritical with no bottlenecks at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

480 Mbit/s is a *raw capacity* of the bus. But not only the data is being fit within that capacity; other devices on the bus take its time, it embeds the clock signal and so on. But of most importance is the structure of the bus protocol.

USB transfers are always initiated by the host and never by the device (a fun exercise is to match this with the behavior of the *interrupt* endpoint type). So any device wishing and ready to transfer data will wait until the host to actually request the transfer.

The request is going from the host to device, the data could be flowing in both ways, but often there are notifications of a success or failure, so anyway the bidirectional data transfers are required. USB1 and USB2 use the single differential pair to transfer the data in both ways, which is used in an half-duplex fashion. (Even worse, it is LVDS for data transfer and it is sometimes used as two individual wires for control information.) All the wires have the capacitance and inductance; so, before we switch the direction of the signal (host to device or vice versa), we need to introduce some delay. (Original parallel PCI bus has the same concept of *bus turnaround* for the same reason. Compare this with modern PCI express, each lane uses 4 data wires, two LVDS pairs, one of which is always used in one direction and other in another direction, and the USB3, which also has individual LVDS pairs.) It takes away some time, and *during that time nothing is transferred*.

Overall, this time lost for control and turnaround is actually quite big share of around 40%! So *under the best conditions* you won't be able to achieve more than 30 MiB/s of the net transfer speed of the USB.

Answer (score -1):

Simply put it, while the USB 2.0 (and even 3.0) standards allow/have bandwidth capable of delivering their max speeds, other factors come into play.. when you say USB 2.0, that's the standards/technology available, but there isn't a HARDWARE built to support the maximum capacity of USB 2 Standard/Design.. hardware involved:

1. USB Interface (the plug/socket)
2. USB Chipset
3. USB Cable (one of the biggest culprit i believe)
4. Memory speed (hardrive, flash drive, etc)
5. Computing power
6. Interferences (from outside factors, power lines, even motherboard components)
7. Sufficient Power on the USB port

..and more..

Now I'm sure if we really wanted to hit close to the limits we could, put together the perfect hardware components to really push the limits, but ECONOMICS come into play.. Things would be very expensive and people won't really buy them.

This is the same story as hard drives. Did you know that manufacturers are capable of developing hard drives that could last 5-10 years? In fact the hard drives back in the early 2000 seem to be more durable than what we have today... I know i have a Samsung 40GB that's almost 10 years old and it's still alive and kicking , except for a few bad sectors here and there. Now, even w/ the toughest hard drives, we'd be lucky to get 3 years out of it.

The capability is there, the sciences is there, but ECONOMICS is again the issue. Why would hard drive manufacturers build expensive hard drives that will last long? It will be very hard to market and sell. This may not be true for the server class type hard drive though.

Comment: Your answer goes way off topic, and does not actually answer the question with enough detail.